# Unable to run npm command in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: node.js, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines, playwright, bitbucket-cloud

I'm trying to run the following pipeline in bitbucket

```
image: node:14-stretch

pipelines:
  default:
        - step:
            name: Install Depndencies
            caches:
              - node
            script:
                - apt update && apt install -y curl sudo git wget unzip xvfb libnss3 libgtk-3-0 libasound2 fonts-liberation
        - step:
            name: Install package.json
            script:
                - npm i
            caches:
              - node
        - step:
            name: Execute test
            caches:
              - node
            script:
                - npm run execute:test
```

the pipeline is failing in the last step in the script npm run execute:test, I think its caching issue but I'm not quite sure how this can be managed,down below is the error log

```
+ npm run execute:test
> playwright-fw@1.0.0 execute:test /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> mocha
  Dashboard Test Suite
       browserType.launch: Failed to launch chromium because executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-888113/chrome-linux/chrome
```

Try re-installing playwright with "npm install playwright"

Answer (score 1):

NPM does unfortunately not run the install scripts again when you are having cached node_modules available. Playwright uses NPM postinstall scripts for installing the browser afterwards. So you can either disable your cache there or run an additional `npx playwright install` which is probably the better solution for that problem.

Also instead of installing the system dependencies manually, you can use `npx playwright install-deps`, see [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/cli#install-system-dependencies) for reference.

Comment: this command npx playwright install-deps throws 

Cannot install dependencies for this linux distribution!

Comment: Then Playwright is not officially supported on your platform. See here for the supported platforms: https://playwright.dev/docs/intro#system-requirements